# d'Alembert's Solution: Should anything more be added to it?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I have this initial value problem:

$$ u_{tt}- c^2u_{xx} = 0; \,0 < x < 1; \,t > 0; $$

$$ u(x, 0) = 0; \,u_t(x, 0) = 1; 0  <= x  <= 1; $$ 
$$ u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0; t >= 0: $$

Solving it using [d'Alembert's Solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_formula), answer I get is,

$$ u(x,y) = t $$

But that does not satisfy last condition. Putting x 0 or 1 should make u 0. But that is not the case here. Am I missing something? Do we have to add something after d'Alembert's Solution?

Answer (score 1):

D'Alambert's formula is for problems on the whole line (infinite string). Your problem is on a bounded interval (finite string) with boundary conditions.

Comment: @JulianAquirre So what is the answer here? u=0? (by making the solution satisfy bounded interval condition)

Comment: There are different ways to get the answer, that I am sure you must have seen in class, like using the boundary conditions to extend the initial data or separation of variables an Fourier series.